# Continuous linear operator on $L^2(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-integral, adjoint-operators, riesz-representation-theorem

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ be an open and bounded domain and consider a positive continuous linear operator $B:L^2(\Omega)\to L^2(\Omega)$ with the property that if $f\in L^{\infty}(\Omega)\subset L^2(\Omega)$ then $Bf\in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$.

Since $L^2(\Omega)$ is a Hilbert space there is an adjoint of $B$, denoted $B^*:L^2(\Omega)\to L^2(\Omega)$ given by the following property:

$$\int_{\Omega} y(x)(Bz)(x)\ dx=\int_{\Omega} (B^*y)(x)z(x)\ dx,\ \forall\ y,z\in L^2(\Omega)$$.

**Here is my question:** Is it true that the adjoint of $B$ has the same property as $B$, i.e.: $B^*$ is a positive continuous linear operator and

$$\forall\ f\in L^{\infty}(\Omega),\ B^*f\in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$$

??

P.S. By positive linear operator I mean that $\forall\ y\in L^2(\Omega), y(x)\geq 0$, a.e. on $\Omega$ we have that $(By)(x)\geq 0$ a.e. on $\Omega$.

**What I have done?**

I used the Riesz representation theorem to find that there is some positive function $\phi\in L^2(\Omega)$ with $\displaystyle\int_{\Omega} (By)(x)\ dx=\int_{\Omega} \phi(x)y(x)\ dx,\ \forall\ y\in L^2(\Omega)$, but I did not succed to make a complete proof using that fact.

Maybe there is some counter example, but I could not find one yet.

Comment: No, this is not true. Say $B$ has a positive continuous kernel $k$, that is, $Bf(x)=\int k(x,y)f(y)\,dy$. Then $B(L^\infty)\subset L^\infty$ if and only if $\sup_x \|k(x,\cdot)\|_1<\infty$ and $B^\ast(L^\infty)\subset L^\infty$ if and only if $\sup_y\|k(\cdot,y)\|_1<\infty$. This should be enough to cook up counterexamples.

Comment: What is true I think is that if $B$ is a bounded operator on $L^\infty$, then $B^*$ is a bounded operator on $L^1$.